# Do two independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ span $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the following claim:

> Let $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $n \geq 2$ be two independent vectors. Then, $\mathrm{span}(\{x_1, x_2 \}) = \{\alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2 \ : \ \alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is a **plane** with dimension $2$.

I cannot formally see how this holds. I am used to the basic definitions such that for fixed $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^3$ the set of $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3: \alpha^\top x = 0\}$ gives a plane. I cannot relate this with the above definition, namely taking the span of two independent vectors of arbitrary size each.

Comment: perhaps they span a plane, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general definition you are referring to

$$\mathrm{span}(\{x_1, x_2 \}) = \{\alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2 \ : \ \color{red}{\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb{R}} \}$$

is a plane in parametric form whereas the definition for

$$\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^3\quad \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3: \alpha^\top x = 0\}$$

is a plane in cartesian form.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and for the red part (the correction -- fixed it). Is there an easy way of seeing how these are related to each other?

Comment: @independentvariable In the cartesian form $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is a normal vector to the plane, that is a normal vector to the spanning vectors of the parametric form.

Comment: Many thanks once again. Last question, if you don't mind, how can $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be normal to, e.g., $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n$?

Comment: @independentvariable I'm referring to the case $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$. More in general a plane can be defined by the 2 spanning vectors (parametric form) o by the orthogonal vectors to the plane (cartesian form) by n-2 equations in the form  $\alpha^\top x = 0$.

Comment: thank you for your time :)

Comment: @independentvariable You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

Consider the plane $x+y+z=0.$ We can express this in set$-$ builder notation: $$\{(x,y,z)|x+y+z=0\}=\{(x,y,-x-y)|x,y\in \mathbb{R}\}$$ Since $(x,y,-x-y)=x(1,0,-1)+y(0,1,-1)$ we can express this plane as $$\text{span}\{(1,0,-1),(0,1,-1)\}$$

Comment: Does $(x,y,-x-y)=x(1,0,-1)+y(0,1,-1)$ need to be $(x,y,-x-y)=x(1,0,-1,0)+y(0,1,0,-1)$?

Comment: The point $(x,y,-x-y)$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$, not in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: my bad, thanks!